# System constantly presses space bar by itself

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard

A few minutes ago while watching a movie in VLC player, my video began to pause and unpause periodically (very fast).

I found out that the reason is that my computer acts like if I was holding the space bar. For example when I focused any textbox, it began to be flooded with spaces.

I suspected that the keyboard was broken somehow, but when I disconnected it, the problem persisted. A restart did not work as well.

Any ideas what should be source of the problem? For the past week I also noticed odd behavior with my USB printer – the system would lose connection and then reconnect it.

I have:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- 4 GB RAM
- Intel Core 2 Duo E8400
- Geforce GTX 560

Comment: Does it do it with all (other) peripheral devices removed?  Does it do it in Safe Mode?

Comment: Did you scan for viruses?